# DiscountCurve is not aware of evaluation date in QuantLib python

Tags: python, quantitative-finance, quantlib

I am using quantlib in python. In order to construct a DiscountCurve object, I need to pass a vector of Dates and corresponding discount factors. The problem is that, when I change the evaluation date to account for settlement days, the curve object is not shifted/adjusted properly and the NPV of the bond does not change as a function of evaluation date.

Is there any way around this? Do I have to construct a different DiscountCurve by shifting the dates whenever I change the number of settlement days?

Ideally, instead of passing a vector of dates, I should be able to pass a vector of distances between consecutive dates but the very first date should be allowed to be the evaluation date.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately there's no way around this.  For this particular class, you'll have to recreate an instance when your settlement date changes.

Writing a version of the class that takes distances between dates can be done, but it's not currently available.  If you write it, please consider creating a pull request for inclusion in the library.

Comment: Thanks! Related question: Is it possible to implement DiscountCurve functionality with a YieldTermStructure object? Because it looks like YieldTermStructure has a constructor which is evaluation date aware:
https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/blob/master/ql/termstructures/yieldtermstructure.hpp#L59

Comment: Yes. If you were to write the date-aware class I suggest in my answer, you would inherit it from `YieldTermStructure`.

Comment: In my case, I have all the representations of discount factors available e.g. not only discounts but also yields. Is there a class inheriting YieldTermStructure that is evaluation date aware?

Comment: No, the interpolation-based classes all take the first passed date as their reference.  More info [here](https://www.implementingquantlib.com/2013/09/chapter-3-part-1-of-n-term-structures.html) and [here](https://www.implementingquantlib.com/2013/09/chapter-3-part-2-of-n-yield-term.html).

Comment: Thank you Luigi. This was really helpful!